# .NET Chart Control - Axis X Text Rotation

Tags: .net, asp.net, text, controls, charts

How do I rotate the text orientation of the text on the X Axiz of the Microsoft ASP.NET Chart Control?  I am using .NET 4.

Is this done under the Series?

Answer (score 14):

```
MyChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = -90; // Can vary from -90 to 90.
```

Answer (score 5):

If you also need to change text orientation of Value text in series, you can set up as below:

```
MyChart.Series[0].SmartLabelStyle.Enabled = false;
MyChart.Series[0].LabelAngle = 90; // Can vary from -90 to 90;
```

I hope this is useful for you. :)